Is standard Arabic considered a dead language? What are the differences from Latin?
I fail to see the difference in usage between Latin and Fusha. Maybe not contemporary Latin but Latin from few centuries prior. Is Standard Arabic the most widely spoken dead language?

Do you suppose that a few centuries ago Latin was taught in every school just as Modern Standard Arabic is taught now? And which countries do you mean while speaking about how Latin was used back then?

As is written this really needs some more input, beginning by the questions already asked by @YellowSky ... You should define a basis for a valid comparison between Arabic and Latin and share your thoughts with us.
